# Paying for cloud server when its powered off?

Tags: cloud-computing

I am intending to use cloud computer for my test lab. As this will required 4-5 hrs of daily testing, I am looking for a cloud server provider charges at reduced rate (or not at all) if my machines are off.

Can anyone please advice me few names ?

Thanks in advance.
Cheers

Answer (score 4):

With [Amazon EC2](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/), all you'd need to pay for when the server is off is the [S3](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/#pricing) storage fees, which are quite reasonable.

It looks like Rackspace offers similar options with their [Cloud Servers](http://www.rackspacecloud.com/cloud_hosting_products/servers/pricing) and [Cloud Files](http://www.rackspacecloud.com/cloud_hosting_products/files/pricing) products.